# How to remove an already-installed Visual Studio 2013 extension .vsix file?

Tags: crash, visual-studio-2013

I've just installed [Productivity Power Tools 2013](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dbcb8670-889e-4a54-a226-a48a15e4cace) for my Visual Studio 2013 and then playing with the option of this extension and I get crashed :-(

i.e.

- The `Solution Explorer` window is now empty.
- Cannot exit Visual Studio
- Going for `Tools` - `Extension and Updates` fails too

What can I do to get back to where I was >.<

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Find the correct folder under following folders for this extension and delete it

```
  C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\Extensions
  C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\Extensions
```