# How to uninstall a Visual Studio 2013 extension manually?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions

I just installed an extension to my Visual Studio 2013 app. I decided I don't want that extension so I went to *Tools->Extensions and Updates* and scrolled down to the extension I want to install.

The problem is, the uninstall button doesn't do anything when I click it (and the Disable button is not even active).

[image: VS Extensions and Updates Dialog]

I then tried running Visual Studio as Administrator but that didn't work either.

I searched the web for suggestions and I found one page that said to use the *VSIXInstaller.exe* utility found in Visual Studio's install directory. To uninstall and extension you have to run it with the following command line:

```
VSIXInstaller /q /a /u:{VSIXIdentifier}
```

My question is, how do I get the identifier? Is it the same as the extension version?

Also, let's say hypothetically that using *VSIXInstaller* does not work. Is there a way to manually uninstall an extension?

P.S. As I am posting this Stack Overflow is telling me there might be [a duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646936/how-to-manually-uninstall-a-visual-studio-2010-extension). I read the other question and it's not quite the same. The solution given on that answer is to run VS as Administrator which I have already tried.

Comment: Try this: http://blog.spinthemoose.com/2013/01/02/the-correct-way-to-uninstall-visual-studio-packages-extensions/ or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21903663/how-to-remove-an-already-installed-visual-studio-2013-extension-vsix-file

Comment: Ran into the same issues a while back and wrote up a blog post: Registering and unregistering http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Mar/01/Registering-and-Unregistering-a-VSIX-Extension-from-the-Command-Line

Answer (score 22):

> **My question is, how do I get the identifier? Is it the same as the extension version?**

Extensions are normally packaged in a VSIX file, which are just zip archives. Inside the zip archive is a manifest file that gives the extension identifier.

Here is a view of a SQLite VSIX file, with the manifest file (*extension.vsixmanifest*) highlighted:

[image: vsix archive view]

If you open the manifest file, you will see something like:

```xml
<PackageManifest Version="2.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema/2011">
  <Metadata>
    <Identity Id="SQLite.WinRT" Version="3.8.5" Language="en-US" Publisher="SQLite Development Team" />
    <DisplayName>SQLite for Windows Runtime</DisplayName>
    ...
```

To answer your question, the identifier is the `Id` field in the third line above. In this case `SQLite.WinRT`.

On my machine, I ran the following and was able to uninstall the SQLite extension:

```
vsixinstaller /q /a /u:SQLite.WinRT
```

> **Also, let's say hypothetically that using VSIXInstaller does not work. Is there a way to manually uninstall an extension?**

I think this is a rather broad question. I am no expert on VSIX extensions, but it seems each one can have it's own quirks. Simply deleting a directory, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21903800/1822514), may work 90% of the time; however, there may be extensions that cannot be uninstalled this way. The PHP extension falls into the latter case.

I think the question you are trying to ask is this one:

**How do I uninstall the *PHP Tools for Visual Studio 2013* extension?**

The answer appears to be in your screen shot. If you look in the lower right corner of your screen shot, you will see this text:

> You need to use the Programs and Features pane in the Windows Control Panel to remove this extension.

Sure enough if I take a look at the Programs and Features, I see this:

[image: programs-and-features shows PHP Tools for VS 2013]

Comment: "The answer appears to be in your screen shot." Ha ha, that's funny! I came here looking for the same answer as the OP, and lo and behold, the answer was right there staring me in the face! Using "Programs and Features" did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

Well the above answers didn't work for me, when trying to uninstall the Advertising SDK, F# and Windows Phone crap that somehow got installed into my VS. I couldn't use the Uninstall button on the Extensions dialog, and they were missing from Programs And Features.

I managed to get rid of them all using the tool from https://totaluninstaller.codeplex.com - it seems some guy got fed up with VS too and coded up something to remove these extensions. It works by listing out all extensions you have registered, you can filter that list via config, then when you're happy you can go ahead and uninstall that filtered list. Worked nicely for me!

Comment: Looks like the VS2013 Update 4 caused all that crap to return, so I needed to run it again today. Bleh, MS, bleh.

Comment: One quick note for future readers...  be sure to run your command prompt using *Run as Administrator* or it will not work correctly.  You'll see this warning in other places as well, but I wanted to make sure it was here, too.

Comment: One more follow up comment from someone who just used this tool to remove dozens of extensions...  Even after **TotalUninstaller** said it uninstalled the extensions, I still saw some of them in VS.  To fully remove them from the Extensions list, I used [CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download) to clean the registry (select all options and remove all issues).  I also ran the cleaner utility.  Once this action was taken, I re-launched VS, and the offending Extensions were gone for good!

Answer (score 7):

Total-Uninstaller (https://github.com/tsasioglu/Total-Uninstaller)
will easily remove all that clutter. Just download, execute as administrator and select every thing that has to go.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is pretty simple, you need to uninstall it directly from the "Programs and Features", because it is develop by another company. I hope it still helps.

[image: Programs and Features PHP Tools for Visual Studio]