# Remove An Extension From Vs2013

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013

I installed OzCode and I thinhk it's breaking my debugger, need to uninstall. How? MDN says to go to the properties in solution explorer and click properties so the APPLICATION DESIGNER pops up. But I don't see that at all. How do I get rid of extensions?

Comment: Go to VS main toolbar: `Tools` -> `Extensions and Updates` -> `Installed`. Select your extension and click [`Uninstall`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293638(v=vs.120).aspx).

Comment: sorry forgot to mark i tried this "product cannot be uninstalled from extensions and updates"

Comment: and I've tried running vs as admin same thing

Comment: Check answers here ["How to uninstall a Visual Studio 2013 extension manually"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25234634/how-to-uninstall-a-visual-studio-2013-extension-manually). Probably it will help you.

Comment: will do thanks for the link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an extension cannot be uninstalled from extensions and updates, it is most probably can be uninstalled from the standard **Programs and Features** Control Panel applet.

Comment: Worked great thanks. Bummer I love that tool for debugging

Comment: @AdamWeitzman Very sorry to hear you had an issue with OzCode - please do let us know what exactly went wrong by emailing support@oz-code.com so we could hopefully get you back up and running as soon as possible.