# Vs2019 vsix is not installed

Tags: visual-studio, vsix, vsixmanifest, visual-studio-2019

Here, I have attached my error log.

```
 1/30/2019 5:09:42 PM - Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.CorruptInstanceException: VSIX Installer has encountered a problem. To troubleshoot, follow the steps here: https://aka.ms/pc5ifb ---> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Dependencies.DependencyGraphConstructionException: The dependent package of 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.Professional,version=15.9.28307.222' cannot be found: Component.8B84B9F8-7BCA-41C4-9235-EA560AA96519,version=16.4.0.49.
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.Initialize()
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.GetProducts()
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.IntializePackages()
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.GetPrerequisitesInternal(IInstallableExtension extension, ICollection`1 installedPackages, ICollection`1 installablePackages, ICollection`1 unresolvedReferences)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.GetPrerequisites(IInstallableExtension extension, IEnumerable`1& installedPackages, IEnumerable`1& installablePackages, IEnumerable`1& unresolvedReferences)
       at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.GetInstallableData(String vsixPath, String extensionPackParentName, Boolean isRepairSupported, IStateData stateData, IEnumerable`1& skuData)
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.GetInstallableData(String vsixPath, String extensionPackParentName, Boolean isRepairSupported, IStateData stateData, IEnumerable`1& skuData)
       at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionPackService.IsExtensionPack(IStateData stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported)
       at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionPackService.ExpandExtensionPackToInstall(IStateData stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported)
       at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize(Boolean isRepairSupported)
       at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize()
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Comment: You even mention *which* extension caused this or if it has VS 2019 support in the first place. Check the message. It's looking for a VS 2017 library version. Check the extension's site, github repo or contact the author to ask when they plan to add 2019 support

Comment: VSIX has dependency and requires VS2017 Professional 15.9.28307.222

Answer (score 1):

I've run into a very similar issue.

Here is the log message:
[Error Log Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aO71j.png)

After hours of searching the internet, I finally was able to find the solution.
I wanted to post it here and give clear step-by-step instructions on what I did so that other people won't have to go digging around the internet as I did.

TL;DR: This is a solution for Windows computers only.

1. First, if you can, you should try to uninstall the extension first. To do that, go to the directory where VSIXInstaller.exe is installed
   (should be located where default Visual Studio is installed; e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\VSIXInstaller.exe`).
2. Then open a PowerShell window as an Administrator in the installation directory. You can also open PowerShell as an Administrator and direct yourself to that directory by using the `cd` command.
3. Then enter this command to uninstall forcefully: `.\VSIXInstaller.exe /a /f /u:<GUID_OF_EXTENSION>` (in your case, that would be `.\VSIXInstaller.exe /a /f /u:8B84B9F8-7BCA-41C4-9235-EA560AA96519`). Note that this may fail due to this dependency failure.
4. If that worked, then good, you can move on to the next step. If not, go to where the extensions are (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions`) and use some search program like [Agent Ransack](https://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/) to search this package ID (and make sure to search it by content) and find the extension package folder that contains this package ID (to find the extension's ID refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25234634/how-to-uninstall-a-visual-studio-2013-extension-manually)). Once you've found it, delete that package folder to uninstall the extension manually. If this doesn't delete the package as well, then refer to this [previously answered StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25234634/how-to-uninstall-a-visual-studio-2013-extension-manually), as there are some extension packages that may be installed on the system and need to be deleted from the `Programs and Features` from the `Control Panel` (if you are using Windows, that is).
5. Since this extension package is considered a dependency, you must also go and delete this extension from `devenv.isolation.ini`, `vsga.isolation.ini`, and `blend.isolation.ini` (they are all located under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE` if you are working with Visual Studio 2019).
6. Finally, using a search program (again I would recommend using Agent Ransack), go to `%PROGRAMDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages` and search for this extension's package ID (or package name; usually available from the `extension.vsixmanifest` in the `vsix` package [Example Package ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8uVv.png)). The search results should show which package folder is declaring this extension as a dependency. Delete that folder.
7. Once the extension is fully uninstalled, then you must find `state.json` and `state.packages.json` and delete the JSON properties that contain this package ID (or package name) (this solution was from this [answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/30748594-74cb-4214-be34-b9749e466e70/vs2019-vsix-not-installed)).
8. Once all of the above steps are done, you should be able to reinstall this extension. In my case, this issue was blocking me from being able to repair, uninstall, or modify Visual Studio completely, and following these steps allowed me to update Visual Studio.

Comment: just to add because I couldn't follow step 7 -> state.json and state.packages.json are from the **cache folder for the VS Installation** (in my case - custom folder in D drive...)

Answer (score 0):

I've run into a very similar issue, too.

Thanks for [D.K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7011003/d-k), your answer works for me.

After I've installed Visual Studio 2022 Preview (version 17.1.0 preview 1.0), I want to update Visual Studio 2019 from 16.11.5 to 16.11.6. But its failed, and it show the following error message:

"The dependent package of 'Microsoft.VisaulStudio.Product.Enterprise,version=16.11.31729.503' cannot be found: Component.Microsoft.ML.ModelBuilder,version=16.7.6.2150501."

[Error Message from Visual Studio Installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7h3Q.jpg)

So, I follow the steps of [D.K's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69548732/9769944).

In my case I should delete the package of "Component.Microsoft.ML.ModelBuilder" for all steps, and the command of PowerShell should change to '**.\VSIXINstaller.exe /a /f /q /u:Component.Microsoft.ML.ModelBuilder**' in step 3.